# Замена одного фрагмента на другой в активити из фрагмента

Tags: android, android-fragment

Собственно я знаю два способа(может еще есть) какой из них предпочтительней?

Код получается на много короче и не надо обрабатывать в активити:

```
getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new FrgListAllWord()).commit();
```

Либо через отдельный интерфейс в onAttach() вызывать метод ативности?

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mCallback.onButtonSelected(v);
        Log.i(TAG,"Передача с Фрагмента");
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallback = (FragmentListener) activity;
        }catch (ClassCastException cce){
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предпочтительнее второй вариант, несмотря на то, что в первом случае код получается компактнее.

При правильной архитектуре приложения, фрагменты ничего не должны знать друг о друге, т.е. не должны обмениваться вызовами напрямую. Это ломает принципы модульности.

Если брать общий случай, при разных конфигурациях устройств может присутствовать различный набор фрагментов. К примеру, на планшете на `Activity` будет два фрагмента, а на смартфоне — только один. Код из первого примера не позволит обработать такую ситуацию, тогда как второй пример позволяет справиться с ней, ведь `Activity` знает обо всех конфигурационных изменениях устройства.

Именно с этой точки зрения, весь контроль над всеми фрагментами должен быть в руках у `Activity`, а сами фрагменты должны быть полностью обособлены друг от друга. Все взаимодействия между фрагментами должны проходить через `Activity` их содержащую.

Comment: Спасибо. Кратко, чётко и понятно.