# Android/Java. Action Bar and TabHost. Как сменить иконку бара при переходе на другую вкладку?

Tags: android, activity, actionbar, icon, tab

В Активити есть Action Bar (стандартный) с иконкой и TabHost..
Необходимо при переходе на другую вкладку таба сменить иконку в Action Barе..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это делается?

Answer (score 4):

Пожалуйста, не используйте TabHost. Эта вещь уже считается устаревшей года 3-4. Есть куда более современные решения, типа TabLayout, который входит в Design Support Library. Тоже самое касается и ActionBar - ему на замену пришёл Toolbar.
По сути вашего вопроса - вам просто надо программно сменить иконку пункта меню. Делается это так:

1) В методе onCreateOptionsMenu() сохраняете ссылку на меню в качестве глобальной переменной:

```
private Menu menu;
this.menu = menu;
```

2) В коллбеке на нажатие таба меняете иконку:

```
menu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
```

Comment: А из фрагмента можно также получить доступ к этому меню? или вызвать в фрагменте как то onCreateOptionsMenu.. или заново просто getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate сделать?? У меня просто содержимое вкладки форагмент и потом этот же фраг заменяется на другой фрагмент и вот там в нем уже нужно чтобы иконка меню да и пункты меню сменилось чтобы все...

Comment: @LS2010 по идее можно. но смысла не вижу. Вам же надо не по какому-то событию на фрагменте меню менять, а при смене фрагмента. И смысл тогда лезть во фрагмент?

Comment: "содержимое вкладки форагмент и потом этот же фраг заменяется на другой фрагмент" - здесь код замены не в активити а в фрагменте.. т.е. фрагмент заменяет свое же содержимое (себя) на другой фрагмент.. т..е событие клика внутри фрагмента есть.. поэтому из фрагмента нужно получить доступ к меню получается..

Comment: я пытался сделать через @Override public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu - но в фрагменте это не срабатывает..не знаю почему ?..как

Comment: @LS2010 ах вот оно в чём дело. Нельзя так делать. Старайтесь соблюдать иерархию активити -> фрагменты. Если что-то нужно сделать с фрагментами, всегда делайте это через активити. Тут я достаточно подробно отвечал на схожий вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448445/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0/448627#448627.

Comment: @LS2010 вы уже и сами страдаете от того, что сама архитектура у вас неправильная. Сделаете по науке - и это сразу решит даже вашу изначальную проблему.